# Can charge and potential be related via an integral equation?

Tags: electrostatics

The potential at $x_0$ generated via a point charge $q$ at $x$ is (proportional to) $-\frac q{\lVert x_0-x\rVert}$. Now suppose we have a charge density function $f$ and want to work out the associated potential. Is this the correct formula?

$$\phi(x_0)=\int_{\mathbb R^3}-\frac{f(x)}{\lVert x_0-x\rVert}dx$$

If so, can the formula be inverted to obtain $f$ as a function of $\phi$?

Comment: Yes, the inverted equation is called Poisson’s equation.

Comment: Probably worth making special note of the [Uniqueness theorem for Poisson's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_theorem_for_Poisson%27s_equation) in this context.